# Have I just become immortal?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

So I'm currently playing The Binding of Isaac with the Wrath of the Lamb expansion and the Eternal Edition update.

I've made two deals with the Devil in the same room, the deals in question being *We Need to Go Deeper* and *Spirit of the Night*.

But something is odd here.

[image: no life meter visible]

As you can see, the Life meter above does not display any hearts at all. None whatsoever. I am also unable to collect normal red hearts, though I have not tried this with the other kinds of hearts.

Is this a bug? Have I just become immortal or not, because I'm afraid to try it before I get an answer, and if so should I avoid collecting any hearts to keep it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The next damage you take will kill you.**

You are not at 0 (or below) hearts. You cannot collect red hearts, but you should be a able to collect the blue ones (spirit/soul hearts).

Comment: Damn. And just after you posted this, I did indeed die. BLUH.

Comment: ANd you will stay at no red hearts until your complete price has been paid. You can theoretically be at -1 red hearts, in which case you need two hp upgrades to get an actual red heart back.